# npm + Typescript: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, npm

I wrote a package and published it to npm. The package starts with

```
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";

export interface ...
export class controlplaneDependencies extends pulumi.ComponentResource {
...
```

The publishing and installation works fine. When I try to run the code from a different `index.ts`, it fails with the error

```
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";
    ^^^^^^
    
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
        at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
        at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:353:18)
        at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1073:27)
        at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/cinto/public-cloud-operator/tests/aws/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:431:14)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
```

This is how I am calling the package

```
import * as controlplane from "@bb/controlplane";

stackOutput=new controlplane.controlplaneDependencies("Install dependencies", {
       Provider: awsProvider,
```

I am not sure how to fix this. I tried adding `"type": "module",` but is still fails.

I also tried

```
const aws = require( "@hybrid-cloud/aws" )
```

but then `aws` cannot be accessed inside the interface.

Any pointers are helpful. Here is the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "es2015.collection"
    ],
    "outDir": "./bin"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71327794/npm-typescript-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) help at all? I've had this issue before and that question did not help, but it might for you. I'm also trying to remember how I fixed it.

Comment: the link you posted is the question I asked. lol
I looked at a lot of so links, but it did not help. If you remember how you resolved, it would be great

Comment: Have you tried set esModuleInterop  to true in your tsconfig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to package.json and it is working now

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:typecheck": "tsc --noEmit",
    "lint:check": "eslint src/**/*.ts",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix src/**/*.ts"
  },
  "main": "bin/src/index.js"
```

I also just kept `es6` in my lib. Thanks everyone for the help